# Normals of a Surface Revolution

Tags: c++, graphics

I am trying to calculate the normals for a surface revolution but seem to be missing something. For some reason I can't get rid of this line.
[image]

I first pass the coordinates into a struct to pass to opengl and then calculate the normals using the already created data.

Here's how I calculate the torus

```
    
    for (int x = 0; x < num_heights; ++x)
    {
      for (int y = 0; y < num_revs; ++y)
      {

        mesh[(x * num_revs_) + y].pos[0] = (c + (a * cos(omega * x))) * cos(omega * y) * sphere_size;
        mesh[(x * num_revs_) + y].pos[1] =  a * sin(omega * x) * sphere_size;
        mesh[(x * num_revs_) + y].pos[2] = (c + (a * cos(omega * x))) * sin(omega * y) * sphere_size;
    
      }
    }
```

And then here's how I calculate the normals.

it's just taking the normals of the triangles by getting the vertices and calculating the cross product of the surrounding points and then taking the average and normalizing.

```
 for (int x = 0; x < num_heights; ++x)
    {

      for (int y = 0; y < num_revs; ++y)
      {

        int index = x * num_revs + y;

        Vec3 cur = Vec3(mesh[(x * (num_revs)) + y].pos[0], mesh[(x * (num_revs)) + y].pos[1], mesh[(x * (num_revs)) + y].pos[2]);

        int left_ind = index - 1;
        if (left_ind < 0)
        {
          left_ind = num_revs - 1;
        }
        Vec3 left = Vec3(mesh[left_ind].pos[0], mesh[left_ind].pos[1], mesh[left_ind].pos[2]);

        int up_ind = ((x + 1) * (num_revs)) + y;
        Vec3 up = Vec3(mesh[up_ind].pos[0], mesh[up_ind].pos[1], mesh[up_ind].pos[2]);

        int right_ind = index + 1;
        if (right_ind > (num_heights * num_revs))
        {
          right_ind = 0;
        }
        Vec3 right = Vec3(mesh[right_ind].pos[0], mesh[right_ind].pos[1], mesh[right_ind].pos[2]);

        int down_ind = ((x - 1) * (num_revs)) + y;
        if (down_ind < 0)
        {
          down_ind = (num_heights - 1) * (num_revs) + y;
        }
        Vec3 down = Vec3(mesh[down_ind].pos[0], mesh[down_ind].pos[1], mesh[down_ind].pos[2]);

        int new_ind = 0;

        if (x == (num_heights ) - 1)
        {
          left = Vec3(1, 0, 0);
          up = Vec3(1, 0, 0);
          right = Vec3(1, 0, 0);
          down = Vec3(1, 0, 0);
        }

        Vec3 dir_left = left - cur;
        Vec3 dir_up = up - cur;
        Vec3 dir_right = right - cur;
        Vec3 dir_down = down - cur;

        Vec3 cross = Vec3::CrossProduct(dir_left, dir_up);
        cross += Vec3::CrossProduct(dir_up, dir_right);
        cross += Vec3::CrossProduct(dir_right, dir_down);
        cross += Vec3::CrossProduct(dir_down, dir_left);

        cross.Normalize();

        mesh[(x * num_revs_) + y].normal[0] = cross.x;
        mesh[(x * num_revs_) + y].normal[1] = cross.y;
        mesh[(x * num_revs_) + y].normal[2] = cross.z;

      }

    }
```

Can someone help me out? I'm not sure what is the problem.

Comment: It looks like your calculation is working everywhere except in the black band, correct?  What is different about this location that would / could cause this?  Are, for instance, the vertices nearly the same in some orthogonal direction here?  Could that be causing your calculation, otherwise working in other areas, to be degenerate in this case?  Maybe there is a divide by zero, or the vector has zero length in this area.  What do the normals you are currently calculating look like in this area, that will provide a clue.

Comment: The cross product will be 0 when x = num_heights-1. I can’t see how you would normalise that.

Comment: @Pete thank you! it turns out my indices were off, this helped me fix it